# Correlated Sub queries using MAX and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, group-by, correlated-subquery

I have a database with the tables: VEHICLES (a Blue Honda Civic costing $30k), BRAND (Honda) AND MODEL (Civic).

I am trying to create a **correlated sub query** which will give me the VEH_IDs for the cars with the highest price from each BRAND.

Simply, I want to know for all the brands which car costs the most.

I've attached a picture with the SQL im trying but it's not working. Most likely because I have no idea what im doing. 
[image]

```
SELECT 
BRAND.BRAND_ID, BRAND_NAME, VEHICLE.MODEL_ID, VEH_ID
FROM BRAND, MODEL, VEHICLE
WHERE VEH_PRICE = 
( 
SELECT MAX(VEH_PRICE)
FROM VEHICLE
)
GROUP BY BRAND.BRAND_ID, BRAND_NAME, VEHICLE.MODEL_ID, VEH_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new query on the `vehicles` table grouping by `brandID` to determine the `max(price)`

```
SELECT brandID, MAX(VEH_PRICE)
FROM VEHICLE
group by brandID
```

then create another query that uses the first one joined back to `vehicles` to determine the related `vehicleID`

```
SELECT 
v.BRAND_ID, MODEL_ID, VEH_ID

FROM VEHICLE v inner join
(    SELECT brandID, MAX(VEH_PRICE) as max_veh_price
    FROM VEHICLE
    group by brandID) m on
v.brandid = m.brandid and
v.veh_price = m.max_veh_price
```

then, to get the `brand_name`, join again to your `brand` table on the `brandID` field, and yes, if max(price) returns more than one vehicle, you'll have to go with Top 1 at Roman suggests.

sorry, couldn't read your images at first.

yes, you need to join the model table to vehicle to get to the brandID.  I'm assuming this is an exercise and you're supposed to learn about joins as a result?  don't just take a solution, then, understand each piece individually.

Comment: Im using Access. I can only do a query using one statement.

Comment: if you're using Access, you can create as many queries as you want.